# How can i put a linebreak between my pie chart from Highcharts and legend, in mobile view?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, responsive-design, pie-chart

I've been looking a while for a solution for this little problem.

in large screens, medium and small screens, all nice, as you can see on fiddle. But i need a solution for mobile view, and i want to give a line break (anything like a white-space: pre-wrap) between the graph and legend.

But i can't do that because this a svg image. So, what is the solution?

```
...
legend: {
                enabled: true,
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                width: 400,
                floating: false,
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                useHTML: true,
                symbolRadius: 0,
                symbolHeight: 0,
                symbolWidth: 0,
                labelFormatter: function () {
                    if (this.name == 'Product') {
                        return '<div class="LegendPieChart-MMS"><span style="float:left;"><span style="color:' + this.color + ';" class="ListItem-MMS">\u25CF</span>' + this.category + '</span><span class="number-piechart" style="float:right">' + this.y + 'K</span></div>';
                    } else if (this.name == 'Competition') {
                        return '<div class="LegendPieChart-MMS LegendPieChartCategory-MMS"><span style="float:left" class="LastValuePieCategory-MMS"><span style="color:' + this.color + ';">\u25CF</span>' + this.category + '</span><span class="number-piechart" style="float:right">' + this.y + 'K</span></div><div class="vertical-divider"></div>';
                    }
                }
            },
...
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pedropcruz/0hv2cjjz/17/

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/0hv2cjjz/20/ ? As you can see, you need separate options for `align`, `verticalAlign` and `layout` - to render legend below the pie chart.

Comment: Yes, that's it, but not for all the screens, only on "XS" (Mobile View). How you can do that without CSS? That's my question. I apologize for not explain myself well, I have some difficulty in explaining. And is totally destroyed, my chart is very small too! http://prntscr.com/7c8tyo

Comment: How about using legend below the chart all the time? You can't set CSS styles for legend, so for example set max height for the legend to enable pagination. In your case, you need to disable `useHTML` too. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/0hv2cjjz/21/

Comment: Can't use it, and you will see why. I will explain this with prints screens to understand.

I have a few graphs, and thats why i put them on a object, and i set them up on a accordion. Like this:

http://prntscr.com/7c9hn4

When i open an accordion, that pie chart of that category, will appear. The Poduct and Competition,

http://prntscr.com/7c9i56

In large Screens, very well, this appear with no problems. Medium and Small screens too, and that's why i want to change the legend to down of my graph, to see both (the pie chart and graph)

Comment: I use another strategy. When i am on mobile view, using a slider (flickity) on highcharts. it's possible? thanks.

Comment: I think so. Just try to set min-width for the container. I'm not sure about flickity library, I don't know that one.